# Why check Intent's action in BroadcastReceiver if theres an intent filter in place

Tags: android, android-intent, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

Im looking at the Android Bluetooth developer docs and looking at the code snippet here and wondering why would you need to check that intent's action if your already filtering for a specific intent action type.

```
// Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        // When discovery finds a device
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
            BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            // Add the name and address to an array adapter to show in a ListView
            mArrayAdapter.add(device.getName() + "\n" + device.getAddress());
        }
    }
};
// Register the BroadcastReceiver
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter); // Don't forget to unregister during onDestroy
```

Comment: one needs to check it only when multiple intent filters are registered. if you have registered only one intent filter for the broadcast receiver then no need to test it. There are certain cases when a specific intent filter registered returns more that one action in intent, at this stage it is necessary to check action in broadcast receiver.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here as per the given example, its not need to check the condition for action, but in case if you are using a same receiver for multiple actions then its needed to check for the action e.g,

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED);
intentFilter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

Here in this case you need to check for the action in the receiver, because we need to distinguish which broadcast we got.

Comment: While this could be an additional reason, the main reason is for security as described in qbix' answer. I only downvote because it is important for people to realise there is a security reason that many developers would not realise as it isn't intuitive.

Answer (score 15):

The [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html#onReceive(android.content.Context,%20android.content.Intent)) for `BroadcastReceiver.onReceive()` contains this caution:

> The Intent filters used in `registerReceiver(BroadcastReceiver, IntentFilter)` and in application manifests are **not** guaranteed to be
>   exclusive. They are hints to the operating system about how to find
>   suitable recipients. It is possible for senders to force delivery to
>   specific recipients, bypassing filter resolution. For this reason,
>   onReceive() implementations should respond only to known actions,
>   ignoring any unexpected Intents that they may receive.